# how do i make the checkbox appear beside the text

Tags: css, reactjs

Hi i am working on a react todolist and I am having trouble with the CSS, can someone with more experience help me with figuring out the problem I am encountering? No matter what I do I can't seem to get the checkbox to appear beside the placeholder text how do I do this in CSS

```html
import React from "react"

function TodoItem() {
    return (
        <div className="todo-item">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <p>Placeholder text here</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoItem
```

?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the <p> and </p>?

Comment: Try it with [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "span" instead of "p" to fix this.

```html
import React from "react"

function TodoItem() {
    return (
        <div className="todo-item">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span>Placeholder text here</span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoItem
```

Answer (score 0):

The `p` paragraph element is block-level, therefore will start on its own line. The easiest way to put the two elements side-by-side while being able to control the alignment of the `input` is to use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). Add `display: flex;` declaration to the `.todo-item` rule in your CSS.

```css
.todo-item {
  display: flex;
  }
```

```html
<div class="todo-item">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <p>Placeholder text here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **label** tag containing **input** tag, like in example below.
Hope this will solve your problem.

```html
<div className="todo-item">
  <label for="test">
    <input type="checkbox" id="test" /> Placeholder text here
  </label>   
</div>
```